# Flutter Unit Test for Create Constructor

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

My question is: How can I run the test aiming to test de loadSpecies() called inside constructor initialize?

**Class**

```
   class TodoProvider with ChangeNotifier {
       TodoProvider() {
          loadSpecies();
       }
              
       loadSpecies() {
          /* Here is the request to API */
       }
    }
```

**Test**
What I need to do here?

```
test('Initialization', () async {
   when(EstablishmentProvider());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside when you will have to mock the api request which you will be doing in loadSpecies() method.

Lets you are getting http client object inside your constructor like this:

```
class TodoProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final Client client;
  TodoProvider(this.client) {
    loadSpecies();
  }

  loadSpecies() {
    /* Here is the request to API */
  }
}
```

To mock the api, you will have create mock class of your http client.

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements Client {}
```

and then initialise an object of the MockClient

```
final client = MockClient();
```

Then, mock the api using client variable

```
when(()=> client.get(any()).thenAnswer(() async => \* return whatever object */);
```

To test the output of your method loadSpecies(), you can use ***expect()*** method